# Any way to display plist number value in hex in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I saved some color value in a plist for configuration. But plist editor will convert the value I saved into decimal, it's not a good way for me to figure it out as a color.

Is there any way to change the way in plist editor to display number value in hex? I don't know where I can set.

Answer (score 3):

Use a string type to store the colour and use the format `#rrggbbaa`.

This will maintain the visibility of the colour channels, which is the thing you seem to be asking for, and shouldn't be too expensive to convert back to a number.

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need to write a script to print out the hex versions of the colors. Or, as long as you’re writing a script, an image with squares for each color value so you can see the color itself.